# Cross-platform .NET webview with cookie and javascript support

Tags: c#, .net, webview, cross-platform, winui

I'm developing a cross-platform graphical desktop application in .NET 5. I'm currently using UNO Platform and WinUI 3 preview 3. I need to authenticate users to a remote website and store the generated cookies. I'm looking so for a third-party webview that support cookie injection and/or javascript execution. I can't use the webview already present in UNO because WinUI 3 come with the WebView2 based on Edgium that is currently not available in Uno and so on Mac.
I already tried different webviews like sharpWebview, SpiderEye, WebWindow and Chromely but without any success. In particular, Chromely seems the only one to support cookie injection and javascript execution, but because of the lack of documentation it is not easy to make it works.
Any help about this? Or can you suggest other webviews to try?